# How to Image on Another image using FFMPEG in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

I am working on an Android Video Editor App & I am just a newbie.
I want to Add overlay of image , test, or sticker on video & that can be moved and resized by guestures like of zoom and drag.

Could anyone help me out in this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use the overlay filter in ffmpeg.